# Placing a notebook on top of sefarim

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, jewish-books, kavod, kedusha-holiness

Kitzur Shulchan Aruch ([28:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Aruch.28.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) writes:

> לא ישרטט איזה קונטרס על הספר, לפי שאין קדושה בקונטרס, עד שיכתבו בו
>
> You should not draw lines on notebook [while] on [a holy] book, because the notebook is not sacred until [something sacred] is written on it

Seemingly, once one has written in the notebook, it would be permitted to place it on top of other *sefarim*. Are there any sources that says so (or against doing so) explicitly?

Comment: I think the hava amina here is that if you were to write pesukim in the notebook you could put it on top of a Mishnah Berurah for example.

Comment: @ezra there are quite a few pesukim mentioned throughout the MB too.

Answer (score 0):

The pashtus is that after you've written notes in your notebook (assuming they're any good), it's more kadosh than most modern seforim, due to the way they are printed, and therefore it would be ideal to put your notebook on top. The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch lived before laser printing. See the questions linked [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/130378/kedusha-status-of-modern-seforim) and [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/83998/why-is-public-reading-of-the-haftarah-not-required-to-be-from-parchment/84007#comment387831_84007).