# Taz on Sefer Aftarta: why mention that printing is writing?

Tags: safrus, haftarah, eis-laasos

On the topic of a *sefer aftarta* (a scroll containing the haftarot of the year), the Taz writes as follows ([OḤ 284:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Turei_Zahav_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.284.2?vhe=Maginei_Eretz:_Shulchan_Aruch_Orach_Chaim,_Lemberg,_1893&lang=bi), translation mine):

> ‮א"כ אפי' אם יהיו נכתבים אין להם דין ספר אלא משום עת לעשות כו'
>
> Since this is the case [that we rely on עת לעשות לה׳], then even if the haftarot were written [as a scroll], it [ie. the scroll] wouldn't have the status of a sefer, but rather [it's permitted] because עת לעשות לה׳ ["it is time to act for the Lord"] etc.

Because the *sefer aftarta* doesn't have the status of a sefer, he sees no reason to prefer a *sefer aftarta* to a printed text, as he goes on to explain:

> ה"נ בחומשים הנדפסים דהדפוס יש לו ממש דין כתיבה
>
> so too in printed chumashim, since printing has the full status of writing

Now, if עת לעשות לה׳ means that there are no requirements for a *sefer aftarta* (it doesn't need to be kosher ink, on parchment, with *sirtut*, etc. as extrapolated by [this article](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/711551/rabbi-josh-flug/reading-the-haftorah-from-printed-materials/)), then why does the Taz need to explain that "printing has the full status of writing"? The article just linked mentions that "there is a requirement that the text have some minimal level of sanctity" and "[i]n order to achieve this minimal level of sanctity, the text must be written in a halachically valid form of writing" — where is this all derived from? How would something being "writing" without the other requirements of writing a *sefer* add some "minimal level of sanctity"?<sup>1</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> I know that we require writing in general for *sta"m*, but here we are discussing עת לעשות לה׳ according to the Taz.

Comment: *Es la'asos la'Hashem* means you can bend the rules, but not make something up new entirely. So for example I think the Taz would agree that if you read the *hafotorah* from a computer screen you would not be *yotze* because that is *chaddashim mikarov ba'u*. In other words he is not necessarily saying there is a minimum level of *kedushah*, rather he seems to be saying that what you are doing has something to do with what the *le'chatchilah* would have been and is allowed under these circumstances.

Comment: @pcoz how do you know that's what eis laasos means?

Comment: @DoubleAA The Taz says -  אפי' אם יהיו נכתבים אין להם דין ספר. This is apparently abundantly obvious, because we are talking about an incomplete *sefer*, so of course it does not have the status of a *sefer*. So it would seem that -  אפי' אם יהיו נכתבים אין להם דין ספר אלא משום עת לעשות כו' - means that *es la'aasos* gives them a nominal *shem* of being a *sefer*, and not that *es la'asos* means that you can do something that does not have the *tzurah ha'nidreshes* at all.

Comment: @pcoz Then why mention כתיבה instead of anything else? Do you think he'd be OK with chiseling it into the wall, where there's כתיבה but no צורה הנדרשת of a sefer? Or with a black sheet of paper on which you've whited out all the white space revealing letters (חק תוכות to the extreme), but no כתיבה has taken place?

Comment: @magicker72 Then why mention כתיבה instead of anything else? - Because *kesivah* gives a partial *sefer* a nominal *shem sefer*. Do you think he'd be OK with chiseling it into the wall, where there's כתיבה but no צורה הנדרשת of a sefer? - I don't think so. Or with a black sheet of paper on which you've whited out all the white space revealing letters (חק תוכות to the extreme), but no כתיבה has taken place? - Also not.

Comment: @pcoz It's not necessary to read אלא משום עת לעשות לה׳ as meaning that עת לעשות לה׳ gives the ספר אפטרתא a שם ספר. It could be that עת לעשות לה׳ allows us to read from something that isn't a ספר. It's not "abundantly obvious" that something written on klaf כדין doesn't have a higher status of being sefer-like over a printed chumash.

Comment: @magicker72 If something has no *shem sefer bichlal* how can it have a higher status?

Comment: @pcoz The sofer says the words before writing, the sofer can be mekudash each shem one by one, ...