# Do I fulfill the Haftorah if I use the back of a Chumash to lein it?

Tags: halacha, haftarah

Let's say I have a Chumash that has Haftarot at the back of the book. Am I yotze reading the Haftorah if I read from that?

Comment: what else would you use?

Comment: @MosesSupposes a haftara scroll. I don't think he is talking about following along but leining

Comment: @RabbiKaii Does anyone use such a thing?  I've never seen it?

Comment: @MosesSupposes We have one at my synagogue but people rarely use it due to the lack of vowels

Comment: @MosesSupposes we do at my shul. However, the OP might be thinking that you have to use a tanach

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/83998/why-is-public-reading-of-the-haftarah-not-required-to-be-from-parchment

Comment: @יהושעק I always assumed that no one pays sofrim to write them because they aren't needed, although I did wonder why our tikkun has the same layout for haftoros as the parshiyos

Comment: @MosesSupposes they really use the back of the siddur in your shul to lein haftara? I've been there, I'm not sure I remember that!

Comment: @RabbiKaii I think they usually use a haftorah book, which is basically just the relevant excerpts of Nach compiled together, but that's functionally the same?

Comment: At all the shuls I'd been to as a child, they used scrolls. Where I go now they don't even read it out loud, but rather each person reads it to themselves quietly (apparently this is a Chassidish minhag?). And in between, I had visited a shul that was making a kiddush because they finally finished getting all the haftora scrolls written.